Python Regex matching only last occurrence while using re.findall
I am observing a strange behavior, while parsing texts from a html file using python regex. Would greatly appreciate your suggestions on regex which I should use.
string = "<a href='https://academia/course/3743'>3743</a>, <a href='https://academia/course/3963'>3963</a>,    <a href='https://academia/course/3850'>3850</a>,"
# I want to extract 3743, 3963, 3850 from the above text
pattern = r".*?<a href='.*'>([0-9]+)</a>,.*"
result = re.findall(pattern, string)
print(result)

# Output
['3850']

It is printing only the last occurence and leaving out rest. I tried following this as well, but it doesn't help
python findall finds only the last occurrence
Can anybody please help with the regex I should use to get all the numbers
# expected output
[3743, 3963, 3850]

PS: I can't use any other python modules like bs4. I need to stick with native python modules.

This question is very similar to this one

When looking for a pattern in a string using regex and findall, you can simply put the pattern you look for in the regex. There is no need to add '.*?' before and after the actual pattern.
The main problem of your regex is href='.*' which means that  it will try to match any character in the href value as many time as possible. As a consequence, it will not stop at the first '> it encounters, but at the last one, giving you a single number as a result. You can see the behavior if you encapsulate the value in a group href='(.*)'. The actual catched pattern in href='(.*)' is https://academia/course/3743'>3743</a>, <a href='https://academia/course/3963'>3963</a>,    <a href='https://academia/course/3850
To prevent this, you must set tell the regex to match any character as few time as possible with href='.*?', the question mark being the identifier for this behavior. It will then stop at the first time it can, so the first '.
You can finally map the output to an int in order to get integers.
The final code, including the regex will be:
string = "<a href='https://academia/course/3743'>3743</a>, <a href='https://academia/course/3963'>3963</a>,    <a href='https://academia/course/3850'>3850</a>,"
pattern = r"<a href='.*?'>([0-9]+)</a>"
result = [int(x) for x in re.findall(pattern, string)]
print(result)

# Output
[3743, 3963, 3850]


That is not the expected output

Can you please elaborate why this is not the expected output?

If you re-read the question you'll see that the expected output is [3743, 3963, 3850] and not ['3743', '3963', '3850'] - i.e., a list of integers rather than a list of strings

I find it more likely that the asker forgot to put the quotes in the expected result, as they don't mention in their attempt (which output ['3850']) that there is anything else wrong with it except what they mention (it's "leaving out the rest").

You can use simple regex for the desired output.
import re

string = "<a href='https://academia/course/3743'>3743</a>, <a 
href='https://academia/course/3963'>3963</a>,    <a 
href='https://academia/course/3850'>3850</a>,"

pattern = r"<a href='[^']*'>(\d+)</a>"
result = re.findall(pattern, string)

print(result)

Output:
['3743', '3963', '3850']

